# JIT not showing debug info

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using VS22.

When my release version throws an exception, JIT (just-in-time debugger) catches and forwards it to VS. However, it seems that it's done too late since the call stack and threads are empty.

If I attach VS before the exception occurs, then I see all the debug info.

No such issue in debug version.

---

As a test, I entered an assert(). It prints the source file and line.

The debugger is attached from JIT. It seems that another process with the same name is spawned (after the debugger is attached). I press stop debugging in VS. This should close the app due to unhandled exception, but it keeps running.

I manually attach the debugger to the process. It complains

"a debugger is attached but not configured to handle this type of exception"

I dismiss it and the new JIT window, go back to VS, and it's attached to my process with all the debug info.
Along the way, the new spawned process is gone.

What is this spawned process that VS attaches itself to?